# iSCSI won't connect to Win10 ENT or Win SVR '12

Tags: windows, iscsi, network-attached-storage

I have an issue getting Windows 10 ENT or Windows Server '12 to connect to a Promise Vess 1840i. I have 2 ESXi servers connecting with no issues over iSCSI.

When I try and connect with the Windows iSCSI tool it finds the NAS, names it, etc. But when I try and connect I get 'The target name is not found or is marked as hidden from login.'.

I've looked in the event viewer and one error under Windows/system shows up. Source: iScsiPrt ID 10 'Login request failed. The login response packet is given in the dump data.' but I've found almost no info on this error.

Could someone point me in the right direction? I'm not sure what I am missing here..

Comment: Looks like authentication on the target is failing...

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how to address that as there is security set up on the iSCSI connection. All that was needed for the ESXI to connect is the IP.